# Change theme for Digits interface

Tags: ios, user-interface, twitter, twitter-digits

need some help with the Twitter Digits SDK. I need to implement a customized color scheme for my app, but cannot seem to modify the scheme of the native Digits UI screens. How do we modify these screens?

Comment: Is this for iOS or Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have much options in terms of customizing the UI, apart from setting a Background colour and Accent colour.

You do this through a `DGTAppearance` instance. For example;

```
DGTAppearance *digitsAppearance =
            [[DGTAppearance alloc] init];
  // Change color properties to customize the look:
  digitsAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor
                                          colorWithRed:81/255.
                                          green:208/255.
                                          blue:90/255.
                                          alpha:1];
  digitsAppearance.accentColor =
                              [UIColor redColor];
```

You'll find everything you need [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/digits-theming).